# How can i get current date for sequential file in DataStage?

Tags: oracle, shell, etl, datastage

Hello i'm having a problem with Datastage sequential file to get the date (current date) for sequential file.

the path i've been using is

```
#WMS_PATH.WMS_PATH#namefile_#DSJobStartDate#.csv
```

but i wanted the format to be YYYYMMDD, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[These date functions are available](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Date_and_Time_Functions.html)

Date format options can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_date_Formats.html)

Alternatively you could try DATE() and format that as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following function in a user variable stage then reference that user variable in the string path.

```
#uv stage code#
DateToString(DSJobStartDate, "%yyyy%mm%dd")

filepath
#WMS_PATH.WMS_PATH#namefile_#uvstage.datestring#.csv
```